# ArrayAdapter<String> constructor is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, android-arrayadapter

My task involves a ListView inside a Fragment.

I'm having trouble populating that ListView.

Here's what I'm trying.

```
public class UrlListFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator, ViewGroup container, Bundle state)
{               
    View returnView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.url_fragment, container, false);

    ListView mylist = (ListView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    String[] urlArray = new String[] { "http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/android", "http://www.google.com", "http://my-favoriate-website.com" };
    ArrayAdapter<string> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, urlArray);
    mylist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    return returnView;
}}
```

I get the error

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<R.string>(Activity, int, String[]) is undefined
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4):

`R.string` is not the same as `String`. Java is case sensitive. String != string.